# Stream Analytics reading csv from Event Hub

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am running into this issue, and I don't know how to get ride of this error:

```
Some possible reasons: 1) Malformed events 2) Input source configured...
```

I have develop a c# Console App to write a csv like this into an Azure event Hub:

```
datacol1;datacol2;datacol3
```

It's working fine, as I develop a reader to check that data is written correctly.

I try to configure an Azure Stream Analytics Job to read data from the previous Event Hub, but nothing arrived in the input. Logs from the Stream Analytics Job said that:

```
Some possible reasons: 1) Malformed events 2) Input source configured...
```

Event Hub is working, Stream Analytics is not working... why?

thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your input - it doesn't look CSV but rather ";" separated values.
Please ensure the console app generated correct input - according to the job input specifications.

You can try your job with a pre-defined input through the portal - click on the input -> Test and see how it reacts.
You can also sample some data from the source in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

Ho men, I just find the way out!!!

Every CSV data in input to stream analytics must have the header!!!

Ho men!